# Confusion on Backbone Marionette and Require interaction for getting dependencies

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I am mildly familiar with `require.js` and `Backbone.js` having used them together for about a year now and relatively new to `Backbone.Marionette` although I am very interested in what it can bring to the table.

In looking for examples of project structure (I can get a little obsessed with this stuff) I have found https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate and other similar examples.

Something that has been bothering me: in their `app.js` file, they return a reference to an *instance* of a Marionette application, ie:

```
var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
app.addInitializer(...);
...
return app;
```

And in many components, they reference the `app.js` via `require.js` and use as follows:

```
define([..., 'app'], function (... , App) {
    App.someProperty(...);
});
```

Now here's what I'm not understanding: I have been under the assumption that the code in their `app.js` is really more like a *Factory* than a *Class* since it returns an *instance* of an application rather than, say, a modified prototype or extension thereof.

Therefore, when they reference `app.js`, aren't they actually creating a whole new *instance* rather than accessing some sort of *shared* instance? There is nothing to suggest that *app.js* is returning a singleton in their code.

And yet, it works, and obviously I am the one who is confused.

So, why does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because objects are passed by reference in javascript and the fact that require.js only loads every dependency once. Then, `app.js` returns an initialized instance, and every other module that requires `'app'` gets reference to the same object.

It's not a factory, it's simply an initialized application object instance.

Comment: Thanks... so to clarify, 1) this is happening due to the way that `require.js` loads dependencies (only once unless asked to do otherwise), and 2) should I rely on it or use a singleton in my own code?

Comment: It works like a singleton because once you included `app.js` for the first time you got an initialized instance. Then every other requirement for the `app.js` references that same initialized instance, because require.js doesn't load a dependency twice, and javascript passes the object by reference.